# rosserial - Arduino DUE - sync issues

Tags: arduino, rosserial, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get an Arduino DUE to work with ROS Kinetic on my machine running Ubuntu 16.04 (using the DUE programming port, although I've tried the native one too).  I seem to be having issues unique to the DUE as everything seems to work perfectly fine with the exact same cone with an Ardunio Uno.

When running the code:

> rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0

I get the following error message:

> [ERROR] [1498484524.793356]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino

Again using the exact same code uploaded to the Arduino Uno I do not get this error.  I have tried a number of different baud rates (all from 9600 - 115200), where I found that the Uno gives the same error if it doesn't have the correct baud rate set, however, I continue to get the same message for the DUE regardless of the setting.

I have tried both my simple custom code as well as the example code provided with ros (e.g. pubsub), but have had not success.  Further to force a specific baud rate I have including the following lines in setup (both individually, and alone):

> nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200);

> Serial.begin(115200);

Using pyserial I can connect to the DUE unlike with ROS.  It appears that others have been successful using the DUE based on other questions on here, however, nothing that I have found seems to resolve my issue.

Any ideas what might resolve the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264764/rosserial---arduino-due---sync-issues/) by [jesse](https://answers.ros.org/users/30910/jesse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2017-06-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jesse](https://answers.ros.org/users/30910/jesse/) on 2017-06-26**:
I've tried pretty much everything suggested related to arduino sync issues included in this question too:

http://answers.ros.org/question/196204/unable-to-sync-with-device-arduino-uno/

**Comment by [jesse](https://answers.ros.org/users/30910/jesse/) on 2017-06-26**:
From rosserial/SerialClient.py (found at https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/jade-devel/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py) line 432, it appears that the given Error is simply indicative of sync timing out.

**Comment by [jesse](https://answers.ros.org/users/30910/jesse/) on 2017-06-29**:
Looking at https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/113
It appears that you need to add:

> #define *SAM3XA*

however, this does not seem to work. There's also mention something about using:

> #define USE_USB

which also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up finding several solutions, however, I would hope that a change to /rosserial_arduino/src/ArduinoHardware.h might make any work arounds necessary.

1 -- First solution that worked.
In your version of ArduinoHardware.h in the Arduino Libraries directory change line 75 to read:

> iostream = &Serial;

This works but will likely make use of other Arduino boards a problem (e.g. Leonardo)

2 -- Put the following code before including the ROS library

> #define USE_USBCON

This also seems to work, however, it means that you'd have to add this in every case you use a DUE, which you might forget.

3 -- Modify the line 73 to read:

> #if defined(USBCON) and !(defined(USE_USBCON)) and !(defined(*SAM3XA*))

Which I believe will resolve all previous issues, however, there might be another board released that also uses the SAM3X... processor and may be an issue in the future.

---

Originally posted by [jesse](https://answers.ros.org/users/30910/jesse/) with karma: 91 on 2017-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rakjoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31970/rakjoon/) on 2017-09-20**:
Thanks a lot. I solved this issue by using what you said. Thanks

**Comment by [quannv](https://answers.ros.org/users/34454/quannv/) on 2018-04-04**:
very useful

**Comment by [jakegoldsmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/34534/jakegoldsmith/) on 2018-04-08**:
Thanks! This finally fixed my problem, after many hours of searching and trying other solutions.

**Comment by [R Valk](https://answers.ros.org/users/38042/r-valk/) on 2018-10-18**:
For me, this does not seem to work. Can you provide us with the full ArduinoHardware.h file?
Tried all three suggestions, but none seem to work.

**Comment by [EwingKang](https://answers.ros.org/users/19209/ewingkang/) on 2019-03-28**:
Thanks! This helps a lot, glad I've googled the issue with "DUE" keyword.